# Error clipping raster NDVI

Tags: raster, clip

I'm using QGIS and trying to clip a raster image with a valid polygon 
(using GDAL), both in the same SRC (EPSG:32622). But the resulting image does not result in a valid raster. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: The raster image (NDVI)]

The values of the input raster:

[image]

On the options, i have checked the option to keep the resolution of the input raster. (It's in portuguese, but it is only to give you the picture, everything else is the default value)

[image]

The result is an invalid raster:

[image]

I found it particularly interesting that the min value is positive and the max value is negative (according to what QGIS is telling me).

Comment: It doesnt have to be invalid just because you have min max values like that. What is the min/max of original raster? What if you apply the same symbology as input raster?

Comment: I tried to do that, but it did not work. Also, i tried to calculate the histogram of the result raster, but it only shows an empty graph. That is why i think it is not generating a raster correctly.